# PCA Minimizing Reconstruction Error

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, pca, optimization

In PCA, we want to fit the best $k$-dimensional subspace to given data $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Specifically, we want to approximate each $x_i$ by $\mu + V_k\alpha_i$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d $ and $\alpha_i \in\mathbb{R}^k$ are parameters we wish to estimate for $i=1,\dots,n$. $V_k$ is a given, fixed orthogonal rank $k$ matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$. An objective function for this problem is minimize the loss $L(\mu,\{\alpha_i\}) = \sum_{i=1}^n||X_i-\mu-V_k\alpha_i||^2$, and I am given one possible optimum is $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}$ and $\hat{\alpha_i}=V_k^t(x_i - \bar{x})$. I'm trying to find this optimum and understand why it's only one of multiple possibilities.

So far I've been able to calculate $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu}= -2\sum_ix_i+2n\mu+2\sum_iV_k\alpha_i \implies\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i(x_i-V_k\alpha_i)$, and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha_i}=-2V_k^tx_i+2V_k^t\mu+2\alpha_i \implies \alpha_i = V_k^t(x_i-\mu)$. Here I'm a bit stuck as to how to proceed, since these solutions depend on each other. However, I do notice that $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_ix_i = \bar{x}$ IF $V_k\alpha_i=0$, so perhaps under the constraint $V_k\alpha_i=0$ for all $i$ we get the desired optimum. Perhaps this is why $\hat{\mu} = \bar{x}$ is not unique. Thanks for any help and thoughts with these questions.

Comment: Because you employ abstract mathematical symbols with little explanation or description, *you have to get them exactly correct.*  In particular, please tell us how "$X_i$" (which is never explained or introduced) is supposed to be related to the other variables and why it does not appear explicitly as an argument to the function $L.$

Comment: Interesting question but context would be helpful: What is being reconstructed and is there any reference paper/book or homework being worked on?

Comment: @whuber I've clarified the question. $L$ is a loss function and we want to optimize over the parameters $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\mu$, hence the $x_i$ are not arguments. I've added the self-study tag as this is part of an assignment.

Comment: @msuzen I've clarified the question and added the self-study tag since this is part of an assignment.